# See what the variable is on a variable change with js?

Tags: javascript, var

I have a variable I will call `x` and I want to see what the variable is when it changes.

Incomplete demo:

```
var x = 0;
x = 1;

whenxchanges = {
    if (x == 0){
        alert(x);
    }
    else {
        alert(x);
    }
}
```

Demo is just showing what I want to happen.

Thanks!

Please no Jquery

Comment: There is no event "simple" solution when a variable changes.

Comment: Well they are not the answers I want. I want a very simple version like in the demo

Comment: [This](https://gist.github.com/eligrey/384583) might be what you want. But, there is no standard Event to test for variable changes. Usually you test for variable changes on a specific JavaScript Event.

Comment: Read the warning at the top of the page first, though.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch#Examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a browser like Chrome or Firefox (firebug) you could run the program step by step, inspect the value, etc...

Besides, you cannot force Javascript to trigger an event when *x* changes.

---

However you could make a function (*setx*), having *x* global, or having *setx* a nested function within a function where *x* is defined:

```
function setx(v) {
    alert("x changes!");
    x = v;
}
```

Then instead of doing

```
x = 7;
```

you do

```
setx(7);
```

and the *alert* is triggered. Replace all *x* assignments with a call to *setx* and you'll be notified whenever *x* changes, ie whenever *setx* is called.

This is of course basic cross-browser JS.

Comment: Can you do cross-browser one

Comment: This is cross-browser...

Comment: ohh sorry about that